# Dynamically mapping xml fields to a static object

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, infopath

I would like to provide the user a visual DOM like representation of an XML structure (here a completed infopath form) and allow them to specify which elements of the xml data they want to map to a statically compiled object.

As an example, the user has an infopath form that allows them to enter a sales deal, they fill it out and submit, the app should allow them to see the structure of the data in the infopath form (in a friendly, treeview kind of way) and specify how it should map to a static representation of the sales deal (think of a row that might go in the "Deals" table).

The Infopath forms (xml source) are not controlled by me.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to display the treeview of the XML and allow interaction with it to specify the mapping (possibly drag and drop?).

This will be in a wpf application (I know I'll have to host the infopath control in a forms host since it is not wpf) written in c#, and we would prefer to use .Net elements provided by Microsoft or open source software.

Edit: As a more thorough example, let's say there is an infopath form that results in xml that looks something like:

```
<Deal id="1" dateBooked="2011-01-01" term="24" language="en-us">
    <Salesman>Jim Flowers</Salesman>
    <FinancedAmount>55000.00</FinancedAmount>
    <Items>
        <Item id="1" quantity="10" unitPrice="10000.00">Tractor</Item>
        <Item id="2" quantity="1" unitPrice="5000.00">Spare Blade</Item>
    </Items>
    <Notes>
        <Note dateAdded="2010-09-20">Customer needs a spare blade</Note>
        <Note dateAdded="2010-12-31">Customer wants to sign the deal on new year's day, I find this odd...</Note>
</Deal>
```

I want the user to, at run time and in an intuitive manner (the user will not know xpath...) map specific nodes of a treeview of this document to a field on my "Deal" object. So, the Deal object might have an id, salesman, amount, items collection, etc. that need to be populated but the notes and some other data are ignored, and the forms will not be the same (info path is providing configurable forms for the user to get data into the system however they want) or named in any consistent matter. The user is specifying the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andreas's solution looks like it would be a good first step.  Looks like for your input it would need to recurse into attributes of the nodes as well tho.

My description of your plan would be:

1. Build a control that shows all the data (Andreas uses a TreeView)

   - You'd probably want to show the Name and the Value for each
2. Build a similar control for the Object you are loading into
3. Setup events to build the mapping

   - You mentioned dragging between them
   - Or if they are both checkbox trees maybe have them check one in the Xml tree, then one in the Object tree and reset both, building a list of the mappings created
4. Finally use that mapping list to fill the object

I don't see any simple way to do it, its a lot of work and a lot of it depends on the specifics of the implementation so I can't just give you code that can do it.

How I think I might do it to get it working quickly:

1. Recurse through the xml generating xpaths as you go for each and every value
2. Load all of those xpaths and the names and values they represent into a table to be displayed to the user

   - With columns for "Name", "Value", "xpath"-hidden, "Load Into Property"-dropdown
3. Build a drop down listing every property in your object, have that in a column in the table displayed to the user

Basically I believe you need to break this down into smaller steps, and search for help on each specific step.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go the simpliest way possible - create a treeview from the given xml and add a checkbox to each node. When the user clicks the "OK" (or whatever) button, you iterate all checkboxes that are checked and build your object.

Creating a treeview from a xml is rather simple - this should work (i did not test it however!)

```
public static class TreeViewExtensions
    {
        public static void LoadXml(this TreeView treeview, XmlDocument doc)
        {
            treeview.Nodes.Clear();

            RecursiveImport(treeview.Nodes, doc.ChildNodes);
        }

        private static void RecursiveImport(TreeNodeCollection tvNodes, XmlNodeList xmlNodes)
        {
            TreeNode tvNode;

            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodes)
            {
                tvNode = new TreeNode(xmlNode.Name);

                if (xmlNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                    RecursiveImport(tvNode.Nodes, xmlNode.ChildNodes);

                tvNodes.Add(tvNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: Well basically, you could list all xml fields in a listbox, and all fields of your object in another. When a user drag & drop's 1 field to your object's listbox, you'd need to save this relationship in another object.

I'm not familiar with wpf but this article seems pretty good - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/csdragndrop01.aspx

The "link" Enumeration type looks pretty promising for what you try to achieve.

Comment: +1 A good answer but not necessarily for the question I asked. I need arbitrarily named xml nodes from a document that I do not specify to be mapped to an object I do specify. The mapping is the important part. I'll try and make this more clear in an edit to the question.

Comment: updated the answer... hope i understood the requirements better this time ;-)